# How to keep or store data in forms input fields. after form submitted in react native

Tags: forms, react-native, store

I am new to react native. I have created a form. Now all work fine. But when I submit form. and after I clear expo app from recent apps and start again. then I want to show previous form filled data. in each input.
and user will able to edit it. so in short I want store or keep all input data in input field. so please help. thanks. is it possible. if yes then please help

here is my code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      Place:"",
    };

validateInputs = (event) => {

  if (!this.state.Place.trim()) 
  {
    this.setState({ PlaceError: 'Field Should Not Be An Empty' })
    return;
  }

handlePlace = (text,event) => {
    this.setState({ PlaceError: '' })
    this.setState({ Place: text })
  }
  
render(){

  return (

         <TextInput  maxLength={50} placeholder="Place" style={styles.inputStyle}
         onChangeText={this.handlePlace} defaultValue={this.state.Place}  />
         <Text style={{color :'red'}}>{this.state.PlaceError}</Text>
```

Comment: You can use server side for this or you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: Ok I am getting response from server API. in this response I am getting all form data. so how can I send that response in each of field. means in place there is place name or like this for all inputs. and I want that specific response in specific field in editable format so if use comes again. he can able to edit their information and submit form again

Comment: in `ComponentDidMount` get all previous filled data from server and then set them to `defaultValue`.